# Using 滿喜由 as a male name in Mainland China

Tags: names

I am a foreigner with a difficult name. Could I use 滿喜由 as a full male name in Mainland China without causing too much hassle in communication?

How does 滿喜由 sound to native chinese speakers?

Comment: 滿喜由 sounds  like 滿喜油. It would be a good name for 春藥 (aphrodisiac)

Comment: Could you provide your real name so that people can come up with ideas?

Comment: My real name is Dionisio. Spanish meaning: follower of Dionysus. It is akin to Dennis in English.

Comment: I guess [迪奧尼西烏](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%BF%AA%E5%A5%A5%E5%B0%BC%E8%A5%BF%E4%B9%8C) is too long?

Comment: Yes. I would not like a long transliteration.

Comment: Can you clarify where you got 滿喜由 from? I agree with @TangHo that it doesn't sound that great, but if you clarified what 滿喜由 was supposed to mean, it may be possible to find an alternative.

Comment: 滿 is the surname and 喜由 is supposed to mean joyful

Comment: 樂, 悅, 慶, 歡 can also mean  'joyful' . how about '滿慶歡' / '满庆欢' (full of joy and happiness). You see people are writing comments instead of giving answers because any answer would be based on opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How does 滿喜由 sound to native Chinese speakers?*

滿喜由 sounds like 滿喜油. It would be a good name for 春藥 (aphrodisiac)

樂, 悅, 慶, 歡 can also mean 'joyful' . How about '滿慶歡' / '满庆欢' (full of joy and happiness). It incorporates the surname '滿'(full) with the first name 慶歡(joy and happiness) into a meaningful full name. And it sounds common enough to be a native Chinese name

Answer (score 3):

I guess **喜由** is some kind of transcription of *Dio* in *Dionisio*. As pointed out by @TangHo, this transcription very unfortunately sounds like a sex drug.

The standard transcription of Greek (and derived Latin) *Dio-* is「狄奧」:

- [**Dio** of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dio_of_Alexandria): 亞歷山卓的**狄奧**
- [Cassius **Dio**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassius_Dio): 卡西烏斯・**狄奧**

***Dio***nysus has the alternative **狄俄**倪索斯.

This transcription matches the Greek, Latin, and Spanish ways of pronouncing *Dio-*. The (alternative) English way of pronouncing *Dio-* sounds something like *Dye-oh*, which should be rendered as **戴歐**.

In [modern transcription practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_into_Chinese_characters#Transcription_table),「狄」tends to be avoided in favour of「迪」, because「狄」is more commonly associated with barbarians occupying the northern borders in Ancient China. I would render your name as **迪奧** or **迪歐**.